# Is it OK for a user with a high enough reputation to ignore the rules in "how to ask"?

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions, rules, research

Is it OK for users with a high enough reputation to ignore the rules because maybe they think their reputation gives them some respect that lower-rep users don't have?

Comment: High rep users are *still users*, and are not above the rules. The closure make it clear.

Comment: In case someone wonders: I've deleted all my comments since we've resolved our conflict with rory outside SE. I think he will agree that we both behaved inappropriately and we apologize for that. I wish you all good day.

Comment: <comments removed> The sincere answer is listed below.  The rest of this looks like a malicious rant.

Comment: I deleted my comments as well and agree with @freakish that we behaved inappropriately. I apologize for that.

Answer (score 9):

> Is it OK for users with a high enough reputation to ignore the rules because maybe they think their reputation gives them some respect that lower-rep users don't have?

No.

Comment: You *assume* he didn't make any effort, and although the question is quite basic and can be found with the right keywords, apparently he didn't find it. And he doesn't stand above the rules, the question was closed and downvoted. Never go into a comment war, just take the appropriate actions and move on.

Answer (score 6):

Typically no.

As a somewhat experienced user on SU, I once posted a terrible question. One of the mods then closed it, let me know what was wrong, and fortunately, we never spoke of it again.

As a mod, I've had quite a few situations where a high rep user doesn't seem to get the way we do things, and I've let him know, in very clear terms why and where he's going wrong, and that he's getting treated the same way I'd treat a new user. A new user *usually* gets a comment. Sometimes I delete and ask them to flag to reopen or undelete.

As a user - Vote and flag as appropriate. Optionally and preferably comment (Politely!) to try to clarify things.

So, it's not just no. It's "No, and you should know better. You'd break your old mom's heart you would, you petty miscreant."

You don't even have the excuse of being a newbie ;p.

Comment: Well-spoken. It would be unfair to treat high-rep users or even moderators differently.